# Process leaked file descriptors jenkins ERROR on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Can someone help me to solve an issue "process leaked file descriptors jenkins"?

I tried whit BUIL_ID = dontkillme but it doesnt work.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know more about what you're trying to run but this question came up as a result of troubleshooting an issue I was having so here's how I resolved it. I am using Windows so if you're using something else it may not work for you.

First of all you need to read and understand the Jenkins documentation on the issue: https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors

I had to install Ant first since it was not installed. 
https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

The Jenkins documentation gives you an example Ant script:

```
<exec executable="cscript.exe">
   <env key="ANTRUN_TITLE" value="Title for Window" />  <!-- optional -->
   <env key="ANTRUN_OUTPUT" value="output.log" />  <!-- optional -->
   <arg value="//NoLogo" />
   <arg value="antRunAsync.js" />  <!-- this script -->
   <arg value="real executable" />
</exec>
```

You will change the "real executable" to be the executable you are wanting to run.

See that .js file in the 2nd arg value? You will need to create that. There's a link to this on the Jenkins documentation page too. Grab it here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/1835010/antRunAsync.js?version=1&modificationDate=1184046328000&api=v2

I didn't make any edits to the contents, just pasted it right in and saved it as antRunAsync.js

So now you take your Ant example script I posted above and throw that in a text editor, save as build.xml

From this point you should be able to test on the command line by typing ant and pressing enter. Your application should load in a different window.

If you haven't set up Ant in the Jenkins Global Tool Configuration do so now and point it to your Ant install (might have to uncheck the Install checkbox). In the Jenkins project add a build step Invoke Ant. Set that up how you like according to Ant documentation.

Hope this answer helps someone else who has stumbled across this problem and this question.